# TYPO3 FAL: absolute path for file storage

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, fal

With TYPO3 6.2, my site entirely lives in `public_html/mydir`, which corresponds to `mydir.mydomain.com`.

Now I would like to place file storages outside that subdomain / directory, say, `public_html/otherdir`.

So I tried setting the file storage path to absolute and `/home/username/public_html/subdomaindir/public/`, as such:

[image]

This would result in FAL errors in the backend, no file tree displayed anymore, and the storage going offline.

Can this be done, and if so, how?

And, extra question: If I just set a symlink with

```
ln -s /home/username/public_html/subdomaindir/public/ /home/username/public_html/mydir/public/
```

would that (also) work?

Comment: What errors do you get? Last time I tried to use a local file storage outside the document root, it just worked, but the files were delivered using an eID-Script. That was with TYPO3 6.2, too.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error right now, as users are testing the site during the day

Comment: Oh, sorry, I think I just had a wrong path!